# Accessing data with C++

Tags: c++, database, soci

I'm developing an application from scratch that will be installed in a system with very few resources, and it will access to a database where will save the data obtained and where other processes could query that data.

Finally I decided to use C++ and sqlite, but my problem is to decide layer use for manipulate data, maybe SOCI or ODB, or other.

I have to optimize the time used to store and access to the data, because I'm talking about sensors' information; what do you recommend me to use?, ODB? SOCI? other?

Comment: Just use sqlite C or C++ API.

Comment: yes, It would be a perfect but DBMS can change and the project requires reduce this dependence with a intermediate layer.

Comment: You need to change your mindset a little. ODBC et al might be useful only if you are planning to work with multiple DB implementations at the same time and if the cost of using ODBC is justified. Otherwise adding layers on top of layers does not add any value to your project, especially when you are limited in resources. If you fear that one day you will have to switch DB, hide details under an interface specific to your application to allow for easy change of implementation w/o affecting other parts of the project.